# How would I use a predetermined variable in a Golang Function?

Tags: go, ssl

I'm trying to spoof the JA3 Signature of the Golang http client. I have figured out how to do this however I'm having trouble implementing proxy support.

Code I currently have:

```
dialtls := func(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
    dialConn, err := net.Dial(network, addr)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    config.ServerName = strings.Split(addr, ":")[0]

    uTLSConn := tls.UClient(dialConn, config, tls.HelloCustom)
    if err := uTLSConn.ApplyPreset(spec); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if err := uTLSConn.Handshake(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return uTLSConn, nil
}

return &http.Transport{DialTLS: dialtls}, nil
```

The `dialtls` function is used to spoof the ja3 signature.

However, how would I set a value in the `dialtls` function so I can use a proxy without using global variables?

```
proxyDialer, err = connectproxy.New(proxyURI, proxy.Direct)
if err != nil {
  return nil, err
}
dialConn, _ := proxyDialer.Dial("tcp", addr)
 

config.ServerName = strings.Split(addr, ":")[0]

uTLSConn := tls.UClient(dialConn, config, tls.HelloCustom)
if err := uTLSConn.ApplyPreset(spec); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
if err := uTLSConn.Handshake(); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
return uTLSConn, nil
```

Comment: The code appears to be missing something: you show how `dialtls` is defined, then how you create an instance of `http.Transport` and then recite almost the same definition of `dialtls`. I have no idea what have to be done _and where._ Can you show your attempted solution annotated with "here, in this particular place I'd like to have `dialtls` use a variable I speciay"—something like this.

Comment: the `dialtls` can be a method on a struct. The struct may have a variable you need so `dialtls` will have access to it.